# Sql : Update sql query on the basis of posted values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am doing a query on the basis of posted  values  for eg. following is the query

```
$query= mysqli_query($connect,
                "SELECT * FROM residential  WHERE type='$type' AND unit_type='$unit_type' "
                . "AND  price BETWEEN '$min_price' AND '$max_price' "
                . " AND bedrooms BETWEEN '$min_bedrooms' AND '$max_bedrooms'");
```

now `$unit_type  , $min_price etc are coming from $_POST array`, my problem is that if  i don't receive  any of the  used values `($type ,$max_bedrooms, $min_bedrooms etc )`  in query, then query does not work.  my question is how do i update the query on the basis of only posted values .

Comment: You can have those columns to accept NULL values and possibly use a default value if left empty. Even a ternary operator will work. Many ways to go about this.

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql Server? they are not the same....

Comment: beware SQL injection, use parameters on your query instead of variables in your query strings

Comment: its mysqli sorry about tag

Comment: @Fred-ii- but for that how do i get values if i set null

Comment: what i want to do is if  $max_bedrooms is not set it should not be in  query

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @Sikander if there are empty inputs, then there's nothing to go in there, so how to get values from.... I'd say a ternary operator is probably your best bet.

Comment: I would suggest that you construct the `where` clause dynamically based on the data that you do have.  The resulting query is more likely to take advantage of indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a $query variable and change it by your post values

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM residential  WHERE 1=1 "; 
if($type!=""){
 $query.=" AND  type='$type'";
}
if($unit_type!=""){
 $query.=" AND  unit_type='$unit_type'";
}
if(($min_price!="") && ($max_price!="")){
 $query.=" AND  price BETWEEN '$min_price' AND '$max_price' ";
}
if(($min_bedrooms!="") && ($max_bedrooms!="")){
 $query.=" AND bedrooms BETWEEN '$min_bedrooms' AND '$max_bedrooms'";
}
$result= mysqli_query($connect,$query);
```

Comment: why do i need to use 1=1?

Comment: so you can use AND in all other conditions.. WHERE block of query have to start with WHERE clausule..

Comment: @SanoojT God bless u , really helped :)

Answer (score 2):

you can (should) perform some validating before putting variables into query. There you can check if vars are sent (and valid types etc.) and if they are not, you can replace them with your default values.

There is another way to do this, in your query you can use COALESCE() function where you specify default value if your value is not present ex.: COALESCE('$unit_type', 'coin').

As mentioned in comments, you should be aware of SQL injection. You can avoid it by strict validating&encoding sent variables or by using some prepared statements for composing sql queries (dibi, pdo ..).

Hope it helps :)